# symfony 1.4 doctrine form - introducing a fixed value field

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

EDIT. TO SUMMARISE: I just want SomeForm that extends my DoctrineForms to NOT INCLUDE certain fields. They are NOT editable. The fixed value I want to set in the code somewhere. Hopefully this should be enough info that you don't need to read the rest of this post...

Hi there. Here is my situation:

- I have SomeModel generated by doctrine
- I have CRUD screens for this model in both my frontend and backend apps
- The only difference between these two CRUD screens (apart from aesthetic differences) is on the frontend, one particular field is FIXED. i.e. administrators can change that value if they want, but regular users can not. The value will just be a constant I define in the code. This field should not be displayed in the frontend add/edit screens.

What I want to know is, what is the "correct" way to do this? I can think of a few ways to just hack it in, but whatever I do feels like an awkward workaround.

Is there any proper way to do this extending my Form classes (which BaseFormDoctrine) or somewhere else appropriate?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments below I am actually using doctrine:generate-module which is different to "CRUD" apparently.

ALSO: While I still haven't solved this ideally, I think I know where the solution lies, I just have to dig deeper into symfony forms:
http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation

Comment: Ok, just to clear out: do use use CRUD or Doctrine's admin-generator?

Comment: Doctrine admin generator I think. i.e. php symfony doctrine:generate-module appname modulename ModelName

Comment: `doctrine:generate-module` generates CRUD, not admin module. To generate admin module, you have to use `doctrine:generate-admin`. I know how to help you with admin module, not CRUD, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another form in your /lib/form folder that extends your normal form and then override the appropriate field. The following will remove the field from the form, so that it isn't displayed at all.

```
<?php

class FrontendSomeModelForm extends SomeModelForm {

  public function configure()
  {
    unset($this["some_field"]);
  }

}
```

Or if you were wanting to render the value, but not allow it to be edited, you could do the following:

```
<?php

class FrontendSomeModelForm extends SomeModelForm {

  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidget("some_field", new sfWidgetFormPlain());
  }

}
```

And then create a `sfWidgetFormPlain` widget that just outputs the value and stick it somewhere that symfony can find it (lib/form/widget or something).

```
<?php

class sfWidgetFormPlain extends sfWidgetForm
{
  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param array $options     An array of options
   * @param array $attributes  An array of default HTML attributes
   *
   * @see sfWidgetForm
   */
  protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {
      $this->addOption('value');
  }

  /**
   * @param  string $name        The element name
   * @param  string $value       The value displayed in this widget
   * @param  array  $attributes  An array of HTML attributes to be merged with the default HTML attributes
   * @param  array  $errors      An array of errors for the field
   *
   * @return string An HTML tag string
   *
   * @see sfWidgetForm
   */
  public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
  {
    //optional - for easy css styling
    $attributes['class'] = 'plain';

    return $this->renderContentTag('div', $value, $attributes);
  }
}
```

You then use this form rather than your normal one for the one that you don't want to be able to edit. Check the symfony docs for how to do this, depending on whether you are showing it in a module, or through the admin generator.

Comment: This is pretty cool, and close to what I want. thanks for the detailed response. However, I don't want it to render at all. Is there any way in my new Form's configure() method I can just say something like $this->deleteWidget("password_md5")  ???

Comment: Also, sorry for my lack of knowledge here, it's just the depths of the sfForm widget rendering seems totally like voodoo to me at the moment.

Comment: To elaborate on this a bit further. I noticed that if I change your sfWidgetFormPlain render() method to just return without doing anything, then it *almost* does what I want... but I still get the label rendered... I just want to remove this field entirely.

Comment: Heh, the part in the documentation that deals with this is http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_sub_altering_a_form_object